# Ownership issue (homer software)

Tags: software-installation, ownership

I am trying to install homer software and every time its not completing, the folder is inside my home directory and i started with sudo then to i am unable to install, can any 1 help me to resolve this issue. (below is the massage)

```
2019-06-30 18:06:43 (755 KB/s) - ‘homer.package.zip’ saved [1482491107/1482491107]

        Unzipping...
        Finished Installing hg19

Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findMotifs.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findMotifs.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findMotifs.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findMotifsGenome.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findMotifsGenome.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findMotifsGenome.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/compareMotifs.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/compareMotifs.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/compareMotifs.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findKnownMotifs.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findKnownMotifs.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findKnownMotifs.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/convertIDs.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/convertIDs.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/convertIDs.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findGOtxt.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findGOtxt.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findGOtxt.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findGO.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findGO.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findGO.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotatePeaks.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotatePeaks.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotatePeaks.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeBigWig.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeBigWig.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeBigWig.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeMultiWigHub.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeMultiWigHub.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeMultiWigHub.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotateInteractions.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotateInteractions.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotateInteractions.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getConservedRegions.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getConservedRegions.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getConservedRegions.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getDistalPeaks.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getDistalPeaks.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getDistalPeaks.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotateTranscripts.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotateTranscripts.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/annotateTranscripts.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/checkTagBias.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/checkTagBias.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/checkTagBias.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getGWASoverlap.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getGWASoverlap.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getGWASoverlap.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/loadPromoters.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/loadPromoters.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/loadPromoters.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/loadGenome.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/loadGenome.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/loadGenome.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/HomerConfig.pm
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/HomerConfig.pm': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/HomerConfig.pm': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/scanMotifGenomeWide.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/scanMotifGenomeWide.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/scanMotifGenomeWide.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeChIP-Seq.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeChIP-Seq.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeChIP-Seq.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/preparseGenome.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/preparseGenome.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/preparseGenome.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/GenomeOntology.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/GenomeOntology.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/GenomeOntology.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeRNA.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeRNA.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeRNA.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeRepeats.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeRepeats.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/analyzeRepeats.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/removeOutOfBoundsReads.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/removeOutOfBoundsReads.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/removeOutOfBoundsReads.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/addGeneAnnotation.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/addGeneAnnotation.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/addGeneAnnotation.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/prepForR.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/prepForR.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/prepForR.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/assignTSStoGene.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/assignTSStoGene.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/assignTSStoGene.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findHiCInteractionsByChr.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findHiCInteractionsByChr.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findHiCInteractionsByChr.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getHiCcorrDiff.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getHiCcorrDiff.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getHiCcorrDiff.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/runHiCpca.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/runHiCpca.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/runHiCpca.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findHiCDomains.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findHiCDomains.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findHiCDomains.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/SIMA.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/SIMA.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/SIMA.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/convertOrganismID.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/convertOrganismID.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/convertOrganismID.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeMetaGeneProfile.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeMetaGeneProfile.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/makeMetaGeneProfile.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getDifferentialPeaksReplicates.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getDifferentialPeaksReplicates.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/getDifferentialPeaksReplicates.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/filterTADsAndLoops.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/filterTADsAndLoops.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/filterTADsAndLoops.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findTADsAndLoops.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findTADsAndLoops.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findTADsAndLoops.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findcsRNATSS.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findcsRNATSS.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/findcsRNATSS.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updateUCSCGenomeAnnotations.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updateUCSCGenomeAnnotations.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updateUCSCGenomeAnnotations.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updateGeneIdentifiers.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updateGeneIdentifiers.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updateGeneIdentifiers.pl': No such file or directory
Trouble opening /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updatePromoters.pl
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 836.
mv: cannot move '.new.pl' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updatePromoters.pl': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//bin/../update/updatePromoters.pl': No such file or directory
readline() on closed filehandle IN at configureHomer.pl line 864.
mv: cannot move '.new.cpp' to '/home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//cpp/SeqTag.cpp': No such file or directory
make: *** /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//cpp/: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** /home/krunal/Krunal/Software/.//cpp/: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

Comment: Question is unclear. What software is this? What commands did you try? If not in the Ubuntu Software center, then you probably should try obtain support from the software community first.

Comment: software is homer for chipseq data analysis, command i used is :         sudo perl configureHomer.pl -install hg19

Comment: Edit your question to add any relevant information. I do not know if many users will be familiar with the software, or do the effort to look up the home page themselves. So also helping out there may increase your chances to have help.